# Horizontal natural scroll is reversed

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

After upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, when I enable the Natural Scrolling setting and scroll with two fingers horizontally it works as if I didn't enable it, i.e. the behavior is the same as with natural scrolling turned off. However, when scrolling vertically it works as expected.

Is this intentional or it's a bug? Is it possible to enable natural scrolling along both axes?

My touchpad is ELAN1000 I believe (ASUS K501UQ laptop).

Comment: I have the same on a Thinkpad. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029128/inverted-horizontal-scrolling-ubuntu-18-04